# Using the Quip API, how can you get a list of all threads?

Tags: api, quip

I need to get a list of all publicly-visible Quip documents in my company using the Quip API. I have a service worker account that will make the API calls.

My question: how do I find the root folder to start from?

Quip's API docs tell you how to get info about one or more folders using [Get Folders](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#folders-get) by passing in the folder ids. You can call this again for nested folders, and you can call [Get Threads](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#threads-get) to get information about each document. (Quip uses the terminology "threads," not "documents.")

But where do I start? I need a root folder to start recursing from, right.

Here's what I've tried:

The Get Folders docs say "To find your desktop or archive folder ID, see [Get Authenticated User](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#users-get-authenticated)." I've tried that but it returns folders called Desktop, Archive, Starred, Private, Shared, and Group.

- `Desktop` seemed like a good place to start but its only child is Archive, and...
- `Archive` only contains a couple dozen docs. The meaning of the Archive folder is not documented.
- `Starred` is docs you've favorited.
- `Private` is your private docs.
- `Shared` is docs that have been shared with you.
- `Group` seemed promising because the Folders UI at quip.com/browse shows the word "Group Folders" at the top. But my account's Group Folder list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to this, but since the QUIP API is poorly maintained and not well documented, for those looking to solve the same problem, here is one way:

**Step 1:** Add your company's root folder to your favorite (Starred folder), and drag it to the top of the favorite list.

**Step 2:** Get you authenticated instance:

```
quip_client = quip.QuipClient(access_token=login_token)
user = quip_client.get_authenticated_user()
print (user)
```

You will retrieve a json result with basic information like name, id... and most importantly the `starred_folder_id` for the user.

**Step 3:** Pass the `starred_folder_id` to the `get_folder` method:

```
print (quip_client.get_folder("starred_folder_id"))
```

You will receive yet another json with a key named as `children` which contains values of your starred folders/files in the order it appears on your `quip` app. The first `folder_id` will be your company folder id.

You can now use the `folder_id` to retrieve the rest of your company documents by more `get_folder`.